# Jest (React TypeScript): testing an internal component function: Error: Expected number of calls: >= 1 Received number of calls: 0

Tags: jestjs

I have started to test my code and want to ensure that a specific function is called upon render of component, here's my tsx file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

interface testProps {
  isAuthenticated?: boolean;
}
function App(props: testProps) {
  const runFunction = () => console.log('Hello!');
  if (props.isAuthenticated) {
    runFunction();
  }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className='App-link'
          href='https://reactjs.org'
          target='_blank'
          rel='noopener noreferrer'>
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here's the test I wrote:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const runFunction = jest.fn();
  render(<App isAuthenticated={true} />);
  expect(runFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This throws the following error:

```
 Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just name a mock function like the function defined inside your react component.

You could pass your runFunction as a prop to the component and see that it will be called.
You could also mock console.log like

```
global.console = {log: jest.fn()}
```

and test for its execution

```
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Hello!')
```

Comment: Hmm but what if there are multiple actions happening inside that function? `console.log` was an example, I am more interested in knowing how to ensure if an internal function is called or not

Comment: When you say passing runFunction in the component do you mean this: `render(<App isAuthenticated={true} runFunction={runFunction} />)` but then this will go against the typescript prop definition, can you show an example of the passing you're talking about?

Comment: I was just trying to help you understand why your current code is not working.
It may or may not make sense to pass the function as props depending on your use case. 

When you test your code you should focus on testing the output depending on an input. In this case the output (or the call to an external library) is the console.log call. 

Just do not test the internal code of your component like that, tests should not know about the internal implementation.  

Hope it helps